# whenever i am sending the id from child to parent, i am getting undefined, may i know what i am missing?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

*trying to send id property from counter to counters, so that I can delete the respective React element.*
*in counters component's handleDelete trying to see the counterid, but getting an undefined response, just can i get some help to know why it is undefined, where i believe to get 1,2,3,4,5.

counter.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    value: this.props.value,
  };

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleIncrement}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}
          className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { value: count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

counters.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 0 },
      { id: 2, value: 4 },
      { id: 3, value: 3 },
      { id: 4, value: 2 },
      { id: 5, value: 15 },
    ],
  };

  handleDelete = (counterId) => {
    console.log("Event Handler Called", counterId);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map((counter) => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            value={counter.value}
          ></Counter>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counters;
```

Comment: You're not passing an id to `<Counter>`  Try `<Counter .... id={counter.id}>`

Comment: @gman thanks. it works. forget to add that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any `id` to the `Counter` component. The `key` attribute is only used to identify the component through the app and avoid collisions when you call more than once the same component.

What you have to do is send an `id` prop to your `Counter` component in `Counters.jsx`:

```
this.state.counters.map((counter) => (
  <Counter
    key={counter.id}
    onDelete={this.handleDelete}
    value={counter.value}
    id={counter.id}  // HERE: send an id prop to your component
  ></Counter>
))
```

In this way your component `Counter` will be able to call `this.props.id`.